# Probability on cards and getting jobs on different dates .

Tags: probability

> (i)  When $2$ cards are drawn from $52$ cards , what is the probability of $1$ card being an ace and the other being a red card?

**MY WORK:**

I have two ways  :
($1$) $1$ ace of black colour and the other is red  .
($2$) $1$ ace of red colour and the is red too  .

So  , probability becomes  :
$$\frac{\binom{26}{1}\times \binom{2}{1} + \binom{2}{1}\times \binom{25}{1}}{\binom{52}{2}}$$

> (ii) A person applies for three different posts in the month of April  .  What is the probability  that the person gets the jobs on $3$ different dates  ?

**MY WORK:**

For one job,  probability is $\frac{30}{30}$ ... For the rest two,  it is $\frac{29}{30}$ and $\frac{28}{30}$ . I simply multiply the three to get $\frac{203}{225}$ ...

**AM I CORRECT  ?**

Comment: @AtifFarooq I am not so sure of that. Have a look at my answer.

Comment: @drhab My mistake

Comment: You have over-counted the number of such two-card hands by 1, since the hand {AD, AH} is counted twice in the numerator, one time with AH as the "red ace" and the other time with AD as "red ace." You get 204/(52*51) and the answer below by drhab gives 203/(52*51). It can be done by combinations but you have to notice that one special hand not to count it twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(i) I am afraid there is a mistake in it.

Correct is: $$\frac2{52}\frac1{51}+2\left(\frac2{52}\frac{24}{51}+\frac2{52}\frac{26}{51}\right)$$where $\frac2{52}\frac{1}{51}$ is the probability of firstly drawing a red ace and secondly a red ace, where $\frac2{52}\frac{24}{51}$ is the probability of firstly drawing a red ace and secondly a red card which is not an ace and where $\frac2{52}\frac{26}{51}$ is the probability of firstly drawing a black ace and secondly a red card. The second and third probability are taken twice because in both cases the order can be switched. This is not the case for the first probability (which you overlooked).

Comment: Ummm... It is not said that the cards are taken with or without replacement... Rather the cards are drawn at a time...  So,  shouldn't it be $$\frac{\binom{2}{2}}{\binom{52}{2}}$$ and so on?

Comment: If it is stated that $2$ cards are drawn from $52$ cards and further info lacks then IMO it is most reasonable to go for "without replacement". Also in your own attempt you do that. "Cards drawn at a time" also points in that direction. There is no essential difference between drawing $2$ cards at a time and drawing $2$ cards one by one without replacement.